# boolean value always coming false in csv import

Tags: c#, csv

I am importing a csv file wherein there are 10 columns. Among those there is Boolean column which could be `(1 , true ,false, 0)` .

I am reading the csv file and creating a data-table all is working fine except the boolean value field , it always return false.

Below code for creating the data tabel from csv.

```
public static DataTable GetDataTable(bool firstRowColumnName, string path)
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path);
            string line = null;

            DataTable dtResult = new DataTable();
            if (firstRowColumnName)
            {
                line = sr.ReadLine();
                string[] headers = line.Split(',');

                for (int i = 0; i < headers.Length; i++)
                {
                    dtResult.Columns.Add(headers[i]);
                }
            }

            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.Trim() != string.Empty)
                {
                    string[] lineData = line.Split(',');

                    if (dtResult.Columns.Count == 0)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < lineData.Length; i++)
                        {
                            dtResult.Columns.Add("Column" + i.ToString());
                        }
                    }

                    DataRow drNew = dtResult.NewRow();
                    for (int i = 0; i < lineData.Length; i++)
                    {
                        drNew[i] = lineData[i];
                    }
                    dtResult.Rows.Add(drNew);

                }
            }

            return dtResult;
        }
```

below is the code where i am reading the datatable.

```
machine is an object of a class.
machine.IsLaptop = dt.Rows[i]["Laptop"].ToString() == "1" || dt.Rows[i]["Laptop"].ToString().ToLower() == "true";
```

Kindly suggest why the value is always false.

Comment: are you sure its bringing back a 1 or a true? because your logic is right there

Comment: yaa ryan i have checked if the value is 1 it is still coming as false when the value is assign to the property it is false.

Comment: Maybe it's something related to the encoding of the CSV file You use. Please check which encoding is used.

Comment: Can you grab a copy of what is in the first read "line" before it gets split, and go into the CSV and get a copy of its first data line, and then post both?  It would help to see what the actual values you are seeing are.

Comment: Try using .Trim() any time you're doing string comparison.  Caused me plenty of headaches...

Answer (score 2):

Since you're working with string values, the value being read probably is " true " including the spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Convert.ToBoolean` and/or with `Convert.ToInt32` to translate your values.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.toboolean%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

You may need some logic to handle cases where you do not get a [Boolean.TrueString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.truestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [Boolean.FalseString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.falsestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). In that case you can [Boolean.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)